# C# MS SQL Update statement not updating database

Tags: c#, sql

I have a local MS SQL Database, and I want to update one of it's bit field.
I have the following code:

```
static void UpgradeVevo(string nev)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Vevok SET Torzsvendeg=True Where Nev=" + nev, connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(nev+" mostmár törzsvendég");
    }
```

Torzsvendeg is a bit datatype(I have tried to set its value to 1 too), and Nev is varchar.

The connectionstring should be fine, since I have tried Select in another method and it works fine. The above code throws no exceptions, but the table does not get updated.

I have tried to find an answer for quite some time, with no success :/. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Does a column exist where the database field `Nev` matches the variable `nev`? Also, use parameterised queries, your statement is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you for your tip, I will, I just want to figure this out first. The Vevok table contains one record so far, where the Nev is vevo1. The variable nev is vevo1.

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column is a boolean (bit in sql server) then you will have to write

`Torzsvendeg=1`

instead of

`Torzsvendeg='True'`
or
`Torzsvendeg=True`

**Edit:**

Please try this:

```
static void UpgradeVevo(string nev)
{
    var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    connection.Open(); // try doing this without a using
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Vevok SET Torzsvendeg=@enabled Where Nev=@nev", connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"enabled", 1);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"nev", "vevo123");
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    command.Parameters.Clear(); // always clear after executed
    // close connection when you shut down your application
    connection.Close();
    connection.Dispose();

    Console.WriteLine(nev+" mostmár törzsvendég");
}
```

Comment: I have also tried that with no success, the database is still not updated.

Comment: Does the column has to be varchar?
I usually use nvarchar(256) or nvarchar(512) for stuff like mails and ntext for text.
Can you maybe try that?

Comment: Tried, and it still shows False. I have no idea what am i missing(Im not forgetting to refresh the table)...

Comment: Im using a local database, and I have found that VS is creating a copy of my db to bin/debug and when I'm updating the table it's updating the copy of my db and not the original. I have checked, and the copied db's field in bin/debug is True. Now to figure out how to update the original too/instead...

Comment: Why you dont work with that in you bin folder instead? When you will switch to a database on a server this can not happen anyway.

Comment: im glad i could help you, do you want to see an example for a parameterized query that returns anything as well?

Comment: Thank you very much, but I have already changed it to parameterized query after you, and the others have suggested :)

Answer (score 1):

`True` should be in a single quote since it's a string literal like

```
UPDATE Vevok SET Torzsvendeg='True'
```

Well brother, you are messed up with quotes. Your query should look like

```
"UPDATE Vevok SET Torzsvendeg = 1 Where Nev = '" + nev + "'"
```

Again, use parametarized query and not this concatenated one to avoid *SQL Injection*

Comment: There is only one record in my table so far(as I'm trying to figure this out first), where the Nev is vevo1. I pass that paramater, but now it gives an SqlException, "Invalid column name 'vevo1'.". I don't really get what I'm doing wrong still :D

Comment: @Hevesi, umm .. mind checking the update in answer again

Comment: Yes, I know about SQL injection, and I will definetely use parametarized query once I figure this out :D Although, there are no exceptions this time, but its still not updated in the database...

Comment: As I have mentioned I have a local db, and for some reason Visual Studio creates a copy of my db to bin/debug, and when I'm updating the db, its updating that copy of my db, not the original db.... The question now is how can I update the original db instead...